# Oracle Autonomous Linux 7.9 Apache installed but default page not accessible

Tags: apache, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a new Oracle Autonomous Linux VM 7.9

I've installed httpd, made it available through firewall, started it, allowed port 80 and 443, and checked status to see that httpd & firewalld are running...

I go to my public IP in my browser, and it eventually reports: "took too long to respond"
No requests are reaching the server, as it says "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"

Is there any diagnostics I can do in the VM to see what's stuck?

Comment: What you have done is correct and it should be working. Possibly issue is external to the instance Just to clarify, you have set up a security list rule or network security group on the VNC for the instance? (https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Concepts/securitylists.htm). Also is there is a route to the IG in a route table? (https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Network/Tasks/managingroutetables.htm)

Answer (score 1):

from the error it looks like the firewall is not allowed at the OS level. Would you please elaborate which OCI service you mean by Oracle Autonomous Linux VM? For normal compute nodes you need to allow the port at OS level using IPTABLES command.

Comment: If you need to ask clarification questions, please do that in the comments, not in the answer space. The answer space is for full and complete answers that can be written once all facts are ascertained.

Comment: This a free tier Compute instance using the Oracle-Autonomous-Linux-7.9-2021.08-0 image  under the shape configuration "VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro" with 1 CPU and 1 Gb RAM.  -- I saw that iptables is not installed, and instructions I found utilized firewalld instead. I thought that Oracle would have thought of public access and the image would have sufficient components to get it running as-is. I agree with you, the firewall seems to be the issue. But not sure what you mean by 'firewall is not allowed at the OS level". I've verified its running permanently after reboot.

Comment: (Oracle Autonomous Linux is their self managed version of Oracle Linux - basically a distro of Red Hat)

Comment: Ah... this is a case of RTFM on my part... I will follow the guide more closely. There are steps to take in the console to allow public internet access. I'll try that first, sorry

Comment: Just to clarify the "firewall is not allowed at the OS level"  statement above. This is incorrect.  Most Oracle Linux VM 7.9 will include the firewall see https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/linux-firewall-firewalld